# 'SubFigure' object has no attribute '_cachedRenderer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to add contour labels while also using subfigures, but I keep getting error in title.

My recreation of the pyplot example [here](https://stackoverflow.com):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2)
for i, subfig in enumerate(subfigs.flat):
    axs = subfig.subplots(2, 1)
    for j, ax in enumerate(axs):
        CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
        ax.clabel(CS)
plt.show()
```

Which works fine barring the "ax.clabel(CS)" call, and ax.clabel works outside of using subfigures. There seems to be [other people](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23173/) who have this issue, but no obvious solution. Thanks in advance!!

Note: both python and matplotlib are updated to the latest versions.

The error output is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_35648\2613963086.py in <module>
     17     for j, ax in enumerate(axs):
     18         CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
---> 19         ax.clabel(CS)
     20 plt.show()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in clabel(self, CS, levels, **kwargs)
   6333             All other parameters are documented in `~.ContourLabeler.clabel`.
   6334         """
-> 6335         return CS.clabel(levels, **kwargs)
   6336 
   6337     #### Data analysis

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in clabel(self, levels, fontsize, inline, inline_spacing, fmt, colors, use_clabeltext, manual, rightside_up, zorder)
    233                     self, inline, inline_spacing))
    234         else:
--> 235             self.labels(inline, inline_spacing)
    236 
    237         self.labelTextsList = cbook.silent_list('text.Text', self.labelTexts)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in labels(self, inline, inline_spacing)
    580             con = self.collections[icon]
    581             trans = con.get_transform()
--> 582             lw = self._get_nth_label_width(idx)
    583             additions = []
    584             paths = con.get_paths()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in _get_nth_label_width(self, nth)
    283                       size=self.labelFontSizeList[nth],
    284                       fontproperties=self.labelFontProps)
--> 285             .get_window_extent(mpl.tight_layout.get_renderer(fig)).width)
    286 
    287     @_api.deprecated("3.5")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py in get_renderer(fig)
    204 
    205 def get_renderer(fig):
--> 206     if fig._cachedRenderer:
    207         return fig._cachedRenderer
    208     else:

AttributeError: 'SubFigure' object has no attribute '_cachedRenderer'
```